# pager inside scroll bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, pager

I need help on this
I need to put a pager inside a scroll bar, im using [slider widget](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll)
but I can not understand how to achieve
Any ideas?

[this is what I've done](http://mauriciocastillo.com/clientes/kinema/coleccion.html)
Tks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to center the pager text within the scroll bar? I've managed to achieve this by adding `text-align:center` to the class `ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all`

Comment: hi, let me explain better, i need to create a pager, and each page is a picture, so in this case it would be : pag. 2/7, and the next picture pag.3/7 and so on.